# Execution time of sparse matrix multiplication

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

A key step in a product diffusion study I am running involves the multiplication of a sparse matrix with a vector. The code below reproduces the code with versions in Rcpp and R.

```
#define ARMA_64BIT_WORD
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec multiply(arma::sp_mat A, arma::vec nodes_status) {

  return A * nodes_status;
}


/***R

library(rbenchmark)
library(igraph)

g <- sample_smallworld(dim = 1, size = 1e5, nei = 12, p = 0.65)

nodes <- V(g)
A <- get.adjacency(g)

nodes.status <- sample(x = c(0, 1), 
                       size = length(nodes), 
                       replace = TRUE, 
                       prob = c(0.9, 0.1))

multiplyR <- function(A, n) {return(as.vector(A %*% n))}

sum(multiply(A, nodes.status) == multiplyR(A, nodes.status)) == 1e5 # check if the results are the same

benchmark(multiply(A, nodes.status), multiplyR(A, nodes.status), order = "relative")[, 1:4]

*/
```

When I run this code, the answers from both functions tally, but the execution times are as follows:

```
                    test     replications elapsed relative
2 multiplyR(A, nodes.status)          100    1.30    1.000
1  multiply(A, nodes.status)          100    3.66    2.815
```

What is wrong with the code here? Is there a more efficient multiplication idiom in Rcpp for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The issue being documented here is two fold:

1. the **conversion time** required to transform a sparse matrix in *R* to an *RcppArmadillo* object is larger than `Matrix`'s use of *C* routines.
2. the cost of **copying** vs. **reference** creation.

Regarding 2., the construction of the `arma::sp_mat` uses a copy since it does not have a reference (e.g. `&`) as a suffix. In particular, note:

```
#define ARMA_64BIT_WORD
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec sp_multiply_copy(arma::sp_mat A, arma::vec nodes_status) {
  return A * nodes_status;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec sp_multiply_ref(const arma::sp_mat& A, const arma::vec& nodes_status) {
  return A * nodes_status;
}
```

From here, the slight a slight performance difference between the two is noted:

```
benchmark(sp_multiply_copy(A, nodes.status),
          sp_multiply_ref(A, nodes.status),
          multiplyR(A, nodes.status), order = "relative")[, 1:4]

#                                test replications elapsed relative
# 3        multiplyR(A, nodes.status)          100   1.240    1.000
# 2  sp_multiply_ref(A, nodes.status)          100   2.766    2.231
# 1 sp_multiply_copy(A, nodes.status)          100   3.141    2.533
```

With this being said, we return to the first point: **the `Matrix` functions for *sparse* matrices are highly optimized and directly use *C*.** Examples of said routines can be viewed at [R/products.R](https://github.com/cran/Matrix/blob/0af6938e78e286bdf0dc7f6e7eef91dfd52e8022/R/products.R#L159-L170), [`src/Csparse.c`](https://github.com/cran/Matrix/blob/d12359287303fa19195d0477bda1d24cb95ddb1c/src/Csparse.c#L513-L720), [`src/dtrMatrix.c`](https://github.com/cran/Matrix/blob/ead38f310e2d067311ade71502df9840a374367e/src/dtrMatrix.c#L99-L233). As a result, `Matrix` operations will be far more efficient.

Now, that is *not* to say speed cannot be obtained in *C++*. In particular, if the matrix object is repetitively used in *C++* for multiplication with an instantiation of pass-by-reference (e.g. `&`), then it should be faster than a call to `Matrix`'s multiplication routine.

Comment: But wouldn't the efficiency from repeated C++ multiplication get reflected int the benchmark? In my study, this multiplication is repeated 2000 times; each time A remains the same, while the `nodes.status` changes. It looks like the best way out for me is to rewrite the vectorized portions of the code into C++ loops. The performance when I increase the replications to 2000 in the benchmark doesn't differ.

Comment: The issue is how the benchmark is constructed. In particular, the benchmark happens in _R_. So, what happens is you send the object 2000 times to _C++_ and _C++_ computes the value each time and then returns to _R_ the value. Thus, there is a _transit cost_ that skews the multiplication benchmark. If you called one _C++_ function that repetitively computed multiplication 2000 times in _C++_, the benchmark would be different.

Comment: Okay. C++ loops then.